# Porting A .net Class Library To Windows Store Apps Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have a class library that targets .net 4 and is used across different platforms via Mono.
I now want to port it to be used by Windows 8. I know the name keeps changing but this is currently called a "Class Library (Windows Store Apps)" in VS2012.
I initially started with trying to port everything to a "Portable Class Library" but this was proving too difficult as some things simply didn't have a generic approach that would work on all platforms targeted, and other things that were supported simply weren't available to the compiler.
So I've created a Windows Store Class Library and created links to the existing files of my standard Class Library so updating once will update both.  I am planning on using pre-processing directives to make changes between the two class libraries
E.G

```
#if NETFX_CORE
    Task.Delay(someTime);
#else
    new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(sometime);
#endif
```

My question is if this method seems a sensible approach?  I have the same default namespace and assembly name.  Could this ever cause issues to my compiler? The assemblies target different platforms so would never be used together in the same application but do both sit in the same solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: Note that `Task.Delay` and `Thread.Sleep` behave very differently - Task.Delay just immediately returns a task which will complete later... it doesn't block.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the heads up, is there a blocking equivalent for win 8 apps? I make calls to a third party web service that is sometimes temperamental. A 1 second pause between a retry seems to fix it.

Comment: You'd typically use `await` with Task.Delay - but of course that's only useful within async methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, yes that should work. That specific case is a poor example, because the two implementations function very differently, illustrating that you may need to rethink some aspects of your design. For cases where there *is* a similar API swap (with similar semantics), I personally tend to move the difference behind a helper method, so my "main" code doesn't need to worry about this - just the helper code. Reflection would be a good example of this (the changes to reflection are annoyingly deep).

The two projects with different target platforms should be fine. I occasionally hit an IDE glitch where it complains about temp files. I think this is due to sharing files between projects. I've logged it [on connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/750047/warnings-generated-for-anomylous-files-during-load)

Comment: I've updated my example to be functionally similar in case anyone comes here looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Task.Delay(msDelay).Wait()
```